# PostgreSql: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 42: invalid continuation byte

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I recently installed PostgreSql and I am trying to create a new database.
Unfortunetly I got and error while creating the database:

"'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 42: invalid continuation byte"
[image]

What is the problem exactly
thank you

Comment: It is not a PostgreSQL problem, but a pgAdmin problem. Perhaps there is a database name or a configuration parameter with a value containing "é" and pgAdmin is choking on it.

Comment: Seems like you should report a PgADmin bug

Comment: what is the version of your pgAdmin4 and your windows10 system locale,
and also can you provide all the input values you gave in the dialog to re-produce the issue?

Answer (score 4):

Try to add the following line at the end of the pg_hba.conf file and then restart the PostgreSQL service:

```
host    all             all             all                 md5
```

Comment: Can you explain what this is supposed to do? Perhaps restarting the server alone is the main solution. Why add an entry to the authentication file?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error when upgrading from 4.5 to 4.7, the solution was to restart the pgAdmin server.

My error was:
Error: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Answer (score 0):

It's a conflict between local languages. PgAdmin is in English but maybe in the conf file the lc_messages variable is French, Spanish or something else. Try this

```
lc_messages = 'en_US'
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solutions above.
None worked.

The solution for me was to install US ENGLISH as my language on my windows 10.
Then I did the installation all over again in that language.

It's working now, and I do not have use US ENGLISH as my windows language xD

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple: find the postgresql.conf file on the server
In Windows, it is located here: `C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/16/data/postgresql.conf`
Find the line with the lc_messages parameter
Replace the lines with:

```
lc_messages = 'English_United States.1252' 
lc_monetary = 'English_United States.1252'  
lc_numeric = 'English_United States.1252'   
lc_time = 'English_United States.1252'      
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'
```

P.S: If the file is not in this location, then use the `SHOW config_file;` request on the server.  This will show the path to the file.